# Symfony: How to use the firewall to give access only to the owner of a profile page

Tags: symfony

On my application there are the profiles of some stores.

Now, there are some pages that can be accessed only to the owners, and not to simple registered users.

I'm using the ACL, so, in each controller method with restricted access I use this snippet:

```
    // Check if the current user is the owner of the store
    if (false === $this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('OWNER', $store)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('Non sei autorizzato a visualizzare questa pagina.');
    }
```

Can I remove these lines and use directly the firewall?

Comment: No, you can't. How would you specify the `$store` obj in the firewall configuration?

Comment: I don't know: there are so many shortcuts in Symfony... Maybe there is also one for this :D

Comment: well, you can create a custom [Value Resolver](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/argument_value_resolver.html), but if you need just some syntactic sugar just use the controller's `denyAccessUnlessGranted` helper. What's the problem that you're actually trying to solve?